# Matching keys of two dictionaries (one nested) then adding value to inner nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to match the keys in two dictionaries (one nested) and if they match, add a value to the inner dictionary of the nested dictionary.

The code I am using is:

```
dict_z ={}

    for key, value in full_dict.items():
        match_name_full_1 = key[:-3]
        match_name_full_2 = key[:-4]

        for key_path, value_path in paths_dict.items():
            if match_name_full_1 == key_path or match_name_full_2 == key_path:
                dict_z.update({key: value, 'path' : value_path})


    print(dict_z)
```

The output I get however is

```
'Key': {x: 1, y: 1}, z: 1
```

When I would like:

```
'Key': {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your dictionaries?

Comment: You can’t have this output! Where is *path*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution

```
dict_z ={}

for key, value in full_dict.items():
    match_name_full_1 = key[:-3]
    match_name_full_2 = key[:-4]

    for key_path, value_path in paths_dict.items():
        if match_name_full_1 == key_path or match_name_full_2 == key_path:

            value['path'] = value_path
            print(type(value))

            dict_z.update({key: value})
```

Not the most pretty but it works.